# OpenVolumeMesh, how to get coordinates from VertexHandle?

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh, vertex, openmesh

I'm using OpenVolumeMesh and have so far been unable to figure out how to get the actual x, y, z coordinates from a VertexHandle. I have the following:

```
VertexHandle vh0 = mesh.halfedge(*he_it).from_vertex();
VertexHandle vh1 = mesh.halfedge(*he_it).to_vertex();
```

In OpenMesh, I could get a point using something like:

```
myPoint = mesh.point(*fvit++);
float x = myPoint[0];
float y = myPoint[1];
float z = myPoint[2];
```

How would I go about doing the same in OpenVolumeMesh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OpenVolumeMesh the function returning the position is called `vertex`.
Other than that you can access the coordinates in the same way.

```
auto myPoint = mesh.vertex(*fvit++);
float x = myPoint[0];
float y = myPoint[1];
float z = myPoint[2];
```